# EF 4.1 Code First Error - IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: database, entity-framework, model, ef-code-first, entity

I am very new to EF 4.1. I am getting the error in my Code First development in EF 4.1.

**"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."**

I searched in internet and understood abt the usage of the

```
[Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)].
```

But no use. I changed the option from Identity to None also. But no use.

Comment: Is the Identity column on the SQL Server side autoincrement?

Comment: yes. Is that a problem ?

Comment: No you are correct. If your Id column is Autoincrement int step 1 you are ok. But as Like below says, you should not append an explicit value for that column.

Comment: if i didn't use the id property in the model class, the below error throws  ---  Unable to infer a key for entity type 'MyEFSample.EntityBase'. EntityBase is the abstract base class for my model classes.

Comment: So you use inheritance. How do you represent your DB? TPH, TPT, TPC? I think you lack of configuration. Check the Fluent API of Code First, and then read this, might help you http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

Comment: hi, EntityBase is my base abstract class. I derived Product class from it. In the EntityBase class has only 1 property called IsDirty of type boolean. In the Product class, I have ProductID, Name, Price property. But when i used the single class, i could save the data to db. Now i creates another class order which is also derived from Entitybase. In the Product class, i added 1 property ICollection<Order>. And same i added 1 property Product in the Order class.

Comment: When i created the objects of both and set the ProductObj.Order = oderInstance. After that i called my ObjectContext to save it. Now i am getting error of Identity issue...

Comment: In my DB, i did not specify any foreign key constarint. The Product table have ProductID as the PK and the order table has the OrderID as the PK. that's it.

Comment: I set the navigation property only in the POCO classes as properties as i explained in the above cmments.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert a new row into a table with an auto increment PK, you shouldnt be setting the ID property here when you try and add it to the DB.

Comment: hi, so are you saying that i shouldn't specify like as shown below

Comment: [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int StudentID { get; set; }

Comment: Then how can i map the fields in the mapping class??

Comment: Nah you shoudnt ever set StudentID

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error because I had defined a foreign key relationship the wrong way in my classes:

```
public partial class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int StudentAge { get; set; }
    public int GradeNumber { get; set; }
    public string LockerNumber { get; set; }
    public string TeacherID { get; set; }
    public string StudentComments { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    [ForeignKey("TeacherID")]
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

    public virtual GradeLevel GradeLevel { get; set; }

    // the code below is incorrect, the StudentClass should have the StudentId 
    // as the FK entity:

    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    public virtual StudentClass StudentClass { get; set; }
}
```

The StudentClass class

```
public partial class StudentClass
{
    [Key]
    public int RowId { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int ClassSubjectId { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    [ForeignKey("ClassSubjectId")]
    public virtual ClassSubject ClassSubject { get; set; }

    // this is the way the relationship should be defined: 

    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```